# Making an EditText field accept only letters and white spaces in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText field in my project which stands for the full name of the person.So I want only letters and spaces to be allowed in it.So I tried the following in the `XML` file

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
```

But it didn't work.Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
yourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence cs, int start,
                    int end, Spanned spanned, int dStart, int dEnd) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(cs.equals("")){ // for backspace
                 return cs;
            }
            if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
                 return cs;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer saved my day. Thanks +1

Answer (score 18):

Below change worked for me:-

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Put space in between your strings. If you put space at the end of a string it will get trimmed off automatically.

I have used space after ending of small letters and starting with capital letters.

Comment: Thanks it help me

Comment: This solution wouldn't work for non-english languages where other characters should be allowed (è,ì,à...)

Comment: perfacto :) Thax +1

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in your EditText tag.

> android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Your EditText tag should look like:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

it works perfectly and no validation condition required

---

## update 1

regex
`src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")`

---

## update 2

Fair enough if that's the case then simply add space in between.

> android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Comment: @AchuthanM allowing spaces was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @AchuthanM fair enough if that's the case then simply add **`space`** in between.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the inclusion of "\n" can not occur at the end of the string, I searched the Google documentation, most found nothing. the only way to achieve spaces and line break is including in the middle of the string. See the example I used in one of my apps.

```
android:digits="aãâáàbcçdeéfghiíjklmnoõôóòpqrstuvwxyzAÃÂÁÀBCÇDEÉFGHIÍJKLMNOÕÔÓÒPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890@-_'+=(){}[]*%$#!?,.;\n: /?\\"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

`android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`

Put space in between your strings. If you put space at the end of a string it will be automatically trimmed off.

I have used space after ending of small letters and starting of capital letters

Comment: Why should this work, while OP's string does not? Please explain.

Comment: I have used this and this works for me. If you add space after your string or before your string it will be trimmed

Comment: @feedMe OP had added space in the end, if you add space after your string then it will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

use regex..
pattern should be

```
Full_Name_Pattern = "[A-Z][a-z]+( [A-Z][a-z]+)*";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please put space between like below string, it working code.

```
 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution, it block entering number, special characters except space.

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
   new InputFilter() {
   @Override
   public CharSequence filter(CharSequence cs, int start,
       int end, Spanned spanned, int dStart, int dEnd) {

   return cs.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]*","");
    }
    }
});
```

Kotlin Version:

```
editText.filters = arrayOf(
            InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend ->
                return@InputFilter source.replace(Regex("[^a-zA-Z ]*"), "")
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your in your `layout.xml`.

```
<EditText android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (whitespace in the middle, not at the end)
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"