# edittext set limited characters in input type android studio

Tags: java, android

i want that the edittext only can enter these characters "0123456789ABCDEF" programmatically.

```
    numOriginal.setText("");
    base = Integer.parseInt(selectorBaseOriginal.getSelectedItem().toString());
    String digits ="";
    for(int i=0;i<base;i++){
       digits+=digitos.charAt(i);
    }
    if(base<=10){
        //numbers
        numOriginal.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance(digits));
    }else{
        //i want numbers an characters "0123456789ABCDEF"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer to the question can be found here
[How to filter the input of EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30259294)

Just some tweak to the code for your case:

```
 InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                    Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                    if (!"0123456789ABCDEF".contains(source.charAt(i))) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Invalid Input",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return "";
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

        };

 numOriginal.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```