# How can I set an Input Filter to accept only BINARY characters (0 or 1) on Android?

Tags: android, filter

Here is my current code which only allows integers. I want to restrict the user even more to only allow 0s and 1s. I wish it were as simple as `!Character.isBinary(..)`, but it isn't. How can I manipulate the start and end parameters to accomplish this?

```
final InputFilter binaryOnlyFilter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for ( int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (!Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i)) && source.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
};
```

Comment: Add this to your editText `android:digits="01"`

Comment: What about including spaces as well?

Comment: In that case try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/26057532/1852441

just replace `if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){` with

`if(cs.toString().matches("[01 ]+")){`

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you! (If you add your comments as an answer, I can mark it as such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  If you just want 0's and 1's , add `android:digits="01"` in your edit text

2)  If you want to add some space as well, then try this answer

[stackoverflow.com/a/26057532/1852441](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26057532/1852441)

in that answer, just replace

```
if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")){
```

with

```
if(cs.toString().matches("[01 ]+")){
```